# Add current date in inputmask placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery

How, if its possible, add in [inputmask's](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) placeholder current date:

```
 $('#call_order_date').inputmask(
    mask: '99 99 9999',
    placeholder: "dd mm yyyy",
 );
```

Instead **dd mm yyyy** writing **02.05.2107**.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet or a fiddle with the  code you have done so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that on the UX side, it is wrong to show the current date as a placeholder.

the placeholder should describe the user what the input mean to be and in 2nd to February the date will be 02 02 2XXX..

any way i think that you just can take the current date and show each number where you want to:

```
var now = new Date();

 $('#call_order_date').inputmask(
    mask: '99 99 9999',
    placeholder: now.getDay() + " " + (now.getMonth() + 1) + " " + (1900 + now.getYear())
 );
```